# How can I measure the percentage amount of a certain colour in an image using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am developing a game that allows users to try and match the sound of a car driving around a track. We want to score people based on how close their sound is to the original. The best way we can think of is to have a visual wave form for them to match and to show the waveform that they are creating. Then we overlay the two wave forms and try to calculate the area of the colour where they overlap. We are currently able to detect colours in an image but not the percentage. Does anyone know of a script that does this? Ideally we would like to do this in browser, but if it can only be done server side then we can try and work with that scenario

Comment: you mean Opacity percentage,right ?

Comment: How does the color relates with the wave**form**? How many distinct colors there will be? On which system do you want to compare them? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference

Comment: We have an existing waveform showing volume in a solid colour on a white background (Yellow). Then we're recording the new waveform as a different colour (blue), and then overlaying it with opacity to show the overlapped area in a 3rd colour (green). I'm trying to find a script that can calculate the percentage of the green colour in the overlapped area.

Comment: Why would you do it? Before you even get the waveforms, you have the data already. Simply check from there where s1 and s2 do overlap. Let the graphics out of the equation.